# gradle specify path for modules inside ear

Tags: gradle

A Gradle build-script creates an EAR file with some jars and one war inside.

**Is it possible to specify a non-root location for project modules (not third-party-libs!) inside the EAR file?**

My project layout looks like following:

```
 ./ear_project            ear/
 ./jar_project_1    ==>     +-jars_direct/
 ./jar_project_2            |            +-jar1
 ./war_project              |            +-jar2
                            |
                            \-war_direct/
                                         +-war
```

---

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the into -> from syntax.  In build.gradle within the ear packaging you can do this - I provded a full example.  The code of interest is near the bottom.

```
apply plugin: 'ear'
dependencies {
   //this works great - war is in the ear.
    deploy project(path: ':web', configuration: 'archives')

    /*
    The following dependencies will become ear libs and will
    be placed in a dir configured via the libDirName property.
    this works great as well.
    */
    earlib group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.2.15', ext: 'jar'
}
ear {
    // put dependent libraries into lib inside the generated EAR
    libDirName 'lib'
    deploymentDescriptor {  
        // JavaEE version (e.g. JavaEE 5 xsd)
        version = "5"  
        //in app.ear/META-INF/application.xml<display-name>"  
        displayName = "My Application ear display display name"" 

       //the xml entry in application.xml - doesn't make the jar itself part of the ear
       module("ejbs.jar", "ejb")

       //use into to define a folder within the ear and put stuff in it
        into ('jars_direct'){
            from('jar_project_1'){
                include 'jar1.jar'
            }
            from('jar_project_2'){
                include 'jar2.jar'
            }
        }
    }
}
```